# mysql in clause vs multiple delete with one commit

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have about 100K records that I have to run for the following query:

```
delete from users where name in #{String}
```

where the string could be 100K strings of this form: Joe,Kate etc.

For performance is it better to run the above statement or delete one record in a loop with one `session.commit();` in the end?

**EDITED**

There could be only one record for each value

Comment: Do you have the names you want to delete in a table already?

Comment: no. I don't have it in another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can create batches of queries to run then breaking it up into batches would most likely be the fastest:

```
delete from users where name in ('name1','name2','name3',.....'nameX');

delete from users where name in ('nameX+1','nameX+2','nameX+3',.....'nameX+X');
```

etc..

If you have the names in a table already you can just do this:

```
delete from users where name in (select name from table_with_names_to_be_deleted)
```

Comment: is your second suggestion better?

Comment: @odelya : A lot of this will depend on your specific system.  Have you done any tests yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better not to use such statements!
The query optimizer will have a field day parsing such a query. I suggest using some temporary table to join against, or some other WHERE-clause that the records to be deleted have in common?